# have some one tried running cadence on cockroach db

Tags: distributed-system, cockroachdb, cadence-workflow, temporal-workflow

The cadenace out of box docker image comes with cassandra dependency, and there are mysql and postgres based images available.
have any one tried running cadence with cockroach db , essentially cockroachdb uses postgres engine for sql.

i tried to change postgres image to cockroach and it did not work

```
   version: '3'
services:
  postgres:
    image: cockroachdb/cockroach
    environment:
      POSTGRES_USER: cadence
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: cadence
    ports:
      - "5432:5432"
  statsd:
    image: graphiteapp/graphite-statsd
    ports:
      - "8080:80"
      - "2003:2003"
      - "8125:8125"
      - "8126:8126"
  cadence:
    image: ubercadence/server:0.11.0-auto-setup
    ports:
      - "7933:7933"
      - "7934:7934"
      - "7935:7935"
      - "7939:7939"
    environment:
      - "DB=postgres"
      - "DB_PORT=5432"
      - "POSTGRES_USER=cadence"
      - "POSTGRES_PWD=cadence"
      - "POSTGRES_SEEDS=postgres"
      - "STATSD_ENDPOINT=statsd:8125"
      - "DYNAMIC_CONFIG_FILE_PATH=config/dynamicconfig/development.yaml"
    depends_on:
      - postgres
  cadence-web:
    image: ubercadence/web:3.4.1
    environment:
      - "CADENCE_TCHANNEL_PEERS=cadence:7933"
    ports:
      - "8088:8088"
    depends_on:
      - cadence
```

Answer (score 0):

Reportedly, some are using it with Cadence and Temporal. See compose snippet here:

https://github.com/temporalio/temporal/issues/287#issuecomment-615135636